# Multiple en.json files getting download on using @ngx-translate/core and @ngx-translate/http-loader

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

Based on the link details I implemented the translation functionality for an angular application having ng-version="4.4.7"

https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular-app-with-ngx-translate

Here are the details in package.json file

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "my-testapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --base-href /mytestapp/",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-stage": "ng build --environment=stage --aot --prod --vendor-chunk=false --common-chunk=false",
    "build-prod": "ng build --environment=prod --aot --prod --vendor-chunk=false --common-chunk=false",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "qrcode": "^1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

At present I have two language json files for testing under the i18n folder with assets.

en.json, es.json

On testing I see that multiple en.json files are getting downloaded.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue

Comment: what do you mean with "multiple en.json file"? can you post a detailed log what and when is downloaded?